# Firebase Hosting & Cloud Functions authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to serve a web app to logged in users and a website to others.

Firebase Hosting has the ability to [Serve Dynamic Content with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). Is it possible to get the auth status within the Cloud Function so that I can return different content?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens . Generate a token on the front-end, then pass to the cloud function and verify the token belongs to the user. Then serve the content.

Comment: @sketchthat - This will be the first load, returning index.html for either the website or app. I can't run client-side code before this request.

Comment: You can generate a JSON Web Token (JWT) client side with the firebase library. Then throw it to the CF.

Comment: This is the request that will return the client-side code. I can't generate anything on the client until after they have requested my code.